# Expand a time series hours into seconds in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a timestamp and value on the hour. I would like to expand the table so that there is a new row for every second within the hour.

This is the data frame that I currently have:

```
             time value
  2020-01-01 00:00:00        1.5 
  2020-01-01 01:00:00        5.2 
  2020-01-01 02:00:00        1.9 
  2020-01-01 03:00:00        2.2
  2020-01-01 04:00:00        3.3
```

This is what I would like to end up with (abbreviated for simplicity):

```
             time value
  2020-01-01 00:00:00        1.5
  2020-01-01 00:00:01        1.5
  2020-01-01 00:00:02        1.5 
  2020-01-01 00:00:03        1.5
...   
  2020-01-01 00:59:58        1.5
  2020-01-01 00:59:59        1.5
  2020-01-01 01:00:00        5.2 
  2020-01-01 01:00:01        5.2
  2020-01-01 01:00:02        5.2
...  
  2020-01-01 01:59:58        5.2
  2020-01-01 01:59:59        5.2
  2020-01-01 02:00:00        1.9 
  2020-01-01 02:00:01        1.9
  2020-01-01 02:00:02        1.9
...  
  2020-01-01 02:59:58        1.9
  2020-01-01 02:59:59        1.9
  2020-01-01 03:00:00        2.2
  2020-01-01 03:00:01        2.2
  2020-01-01 03:00:02        2.2
...  
  2020-01-01 03:59:58        2.2
  2020-01-01 03:59:59        2.2
  2020-01-01 04:00:00        3.3
  2020-01-01 04:00:01        3.3
  2020-01-01 04:00:02        3.3
...  
  2020-01-01 04:59:58        3.3
  2020-01-01 04:59:59        3.3
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `complete` and `fill`:

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  complete(date = seq(from = min(date), to = max(date), by = 1)) %>% 
  fill(value)

# A tibble: 3,601 x 2
   date                value
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 00:00:00   1.5
 2 2020-01-01 00:00:01   1.5
 3 2020-01-01 00:00:02   1.5
 4 2020-01-01 00:00:03   1.5
 5 2020-01-01 00:00:04   1.5
 6 2020-01-01 00:00:05   1.5
 7 2020-01-01 00:00:06   1.5
 8 2020-01-01 00:00:07   1.5
 9 2020-01-01 00:00:08   1.5
10 2020-01-01 00:00:09   1.5
# ... with 3,591 more rows
```

**data**

```r
date =  as.POSIXct(c("2020-01-01 00:00:00", "2020-01-01 01:00:00", "2020-01-01 02:00:00"))
value = c(1.5, 5.2, 6)
df <- data.frame(date = date, value = value)
```

---

If one wants to expand for the final date/hour in the dataframe (credits to
@caldwellst)

```r
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  complete(date = seq(from = min(date), to = max(date) + hours(1) - seconds(1), by = 1)) %>% 
  fill(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Through a sequence of the following should do it

```
data <- structure(
  list(
    time = c("01/01/2020 00:00:00", "01/01/2020 01:00:00", "01/01/2020 02:00:00", "01/01/2020 03:00:00", "01/01/2020 04:00:00"), 
    value = c(1.5, 5.2, 1.9, 2.2, 3.3)
    ),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
  class = "data.frame"
  )


  
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(time = lubridate::dmy_hms(time)) %>%
  complete(time = seq.POSIXt(min(time), max(time), by="sec")) %>%
  fill(value)
```